# Add Embed page section from another website

Tags: embed

Need add webpage section from another website

Can something help me solve quest. I have web site and I need to add page (ads  list) from another website. It would be simple add only iframe but I want add only site section without any headers, only ads list. Can someone share ideas how to do this?